# what is the idea behind this unnecessary method reference?

Tags: java, methods, java-8, predicate

the [Predicate interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) in java 8 has a static method like:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return (null == targetRef)
            ? Objects::isNull
            : object -> targetRef.equals(object);
}
```

why not doing:

```
 return (null == targetRef) 
            ? null
            : object -> targetRef.equals(object);
```

I mean, this method reference `Objects::isNull` is not bringing any further improvement... and is reducing a little the readability...

if is null I return true... Done! or am I missing some pitfall behind the scenes..?

Comment: Actually null would be a valid return value here...

Comment: Please change `true` back to `null`. I underestimated your question, people gave some good answers and it doesn't make much sense with `true` the answer to it as it is now is 'your code doesn't compile'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method needs to return a `Predicate<T>`. Although `null` *is* a valid value for `Predicate<T>`, it isn't really useful in this case.

If the passed in object is null, how do we determine whether something else is equal to it? Well, we check if that "something else" is also null! The code could have been:

```
object -> object == null
```

See how this is a lambda expression, not a `null` literal? If you want to say "check whether something is null" you should write a lambda expression like this, instead of `null`.

The `Objects::isNull` method does roughly the same thing as the above lambda. They chose `Objects::isNull` instead because it is more readable.

EDIT: I see that you edited your question and changed `null` to `true`. This is not correct either.

First of all, `true` is not a valid value for `Predicate<T>`. If you want a predicate that always returns true, you need

```
obj -> true
```

And anyway, this is logically incorrect as well. A null object is not always equal to another object.

Comment: I think `(null == targetRef) ? Objects::isNull : targetRef::equals` would be more readable

Comment: @flakes Nice catch, maybe oracle improved in Java 9?

Comment: @Oleg Maybe! I don't recall seeing the function libs get that much love in the java 9 updates. Java 10 will be more hopeful. If project Valhalla pans out we're going to have a top notch java experience to look forward to! :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the misunderstanding here is that not targetRef is tested for being null, but this method is returning a Predicate (a function) which is testing for equality.

So code like this could be written:

```
Predicate<String> writtenByAuthor = Predicate.isEqual("Firewall-Alien");
```

This instance can be used in other methods using a Predicate, e.g. `java.util.stream.Stream.filter(Predicate<? super T> p)`.

Coming back to your question regarding `null` maybe this snippet illustrates the usage:

```
void printMatching(List<String> list, String s) {
   printMatching(list, Predicate.isEqual(s));
}

void printMatching(List<String> list, Predicate<? super String> filter) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(list);
   Objects.requireNonNull(filter);
   list.stream().filter(filter).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Now looking at this code, regardless of whether `s` was `null` or not, a Predicate testing for equality is constructed testing each element of the supplied list and will print it.
This code also shows, that if you need some flexibility Predicate & Functional Interfaces are your friends.
If your project does not need this flexibility, you can safely decide to not use them and use the well-known ways to test your parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The method is supposed to return a predicate that evaluates to `true` if the object to test is equal to the reference object, to be checked is a `null` safe manner.

It could have been implemented like

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return object -> Objects.equals(object, targetRef);
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return object -> object==targetRef || targetRef!=null&&targetRef.equals(object);
}
```

However, whether `targetRef` is `null` or not doesn’t change after the predicate’s construction and since the predicate might get evaluated more than once, it’s more efficient to move tests for invariant properties out of the predicate and create specialized predicate functions.

The implementation is equivalent to

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return null == targetRef? object -> object==null: object -> targetRef.equals(object);
}
```

returning either of two functions, a function only testing for `null` or a function calling `equals` without testing for `null`, depending on whether `targetRef` is `null`.

This is also equivalent to

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return null == targetRef? Objects::isNull: targetRef::equals;
}
```

However, it’s not clear why the JRE developers decided for a mixture of method reference and lambda expression…

Answer (score 3):

The [Javadoc of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-) states:

> Returns a predicate that tests if two arguments are equal according to Objects.equals(Object, Object).

If `null == targetRef`, then (for another `Object o`) `Objects.equals(targetRef, o)` is true if (and only if) `o == null`.

Apart from that, your code wouldn't even compile, as `true` is not a Predicate.

Comment: The last sentence is my fault, he started with `null` and then I confused him.